# Getting 'Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin.' even tho i changed it to the latest version

Tags: flutter, kotlin, gradle, build.gradle, kotlin-gradle-plugin

android/gradle.build

```
    buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.22'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

plugins {
    id "com.google.gms.google-services" version "4.4.1"
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

app/build.gralde

```
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
    id "com.google.gms.google-services"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

android {
    namespace "com.example.mostadam_new"
    compileSdk flutter.compileSdkVersion


    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.mostadam_new"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    // Import the Firebase BoM
    implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.7.2"))


    // TODO: Add the dependencies for Firebase products you want to use
    // When using the BoM, don't specify versions in Firebase dependencies
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics")


    // Add the dependencies for any other desired Firebase products
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#available-libraries
}
```

gradle.properties

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4G
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
android.defaults.buildfeatures.buildconfig=true
android.nonTransitiveRClass=false
android.nonFinalResIds=false
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7.1-bin.zip
```

i tried almost all version of both kotlin and gradle but nothing works i have the latets kotlin version, the latest version of android studio, everything is up to date, i don't know what's the issue, if anyone can help that would be awesome!

Comment: You are using gradle version 4.1.0 . You should be using at least 7